# external touch pad/board for non-touch laptop

Tags: laptop, monitors, windows, touchscreen

I know that there are tablets and also some laptops/notebooks for which they have touch screen.
Now my question is that: are there any cheap external touching pad or board (for instance 15-inch or like a4 or a5 paper size) together with a pen and probably with a wire/or wireless connecting to my (non-touch screen) laptop, that I can write and draw over it, and see its results on my laptop screen.

If there are, what is its name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best collection of words I can find appear to be "[Drawing Monitor Tablets](https://www.hereon.biz/drawing-monitor/)" which doesn't always exclude those without displays. Read carefully any you might select as they could be a high end digitizing tablet but no display. Having a display (monitor/screen) as part of the tablet makes graphics editing a bit easier, but the prices usually reflect this.

Amazon has many and Wacom is a popular product line:

[image: wacom tablet]

Larger sizes command higher prices, of course, but offer higher native resolution to go along with fine detail entry at lower zoom figures.

Comment: Wacom is anything but cheap, but that's THE brand for drawing AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few options for you, both Touchpads and Graphic Drawing Tablets.

- [Perixx PERIPAD-501 Wired USB Touchpad](https://amzn.to/33kEts6)
- [VOGEK Trackpad Touchpad, JellyComb USB Wired Touchpad with Multi-Touch Navigation](https://amzn.to/2wVKMpX)
- [XP-Pen G430S Graphic Drawing Tablet](https://amzn.to/3d4ZdZi)
- [XP-Pen StarG640 Graphic Drawing Tablet](https://amzn.to/33sCpOP)

Comment: your suggestions are very small size?! My goal is to use that pad as an educational/teaching tool to be able to write my lecture with pen on it.

Comment: There's cheap, and then there's large. Large digitizer devices are spendy.